# Cannot create fluid voronoi pattern

Tags: subdivision-surface, wireframe

I´m really struggling to create a fluid voronoi pattern on this sculpted rock. As seen in the photo, after applying 3 modifiers (decimal > wireframe > subdivision surface) I ended up with this voronoi loooking rock, which is not that bad.

The problem is that I need the middle part (green lines) to be less stretched, for some reason the middle holes are bigger and wider than the ones on the top, ruining the rock structure. I need to 3D print this, so having the top voronoi pattern on the whole piece would be nice

[image]

Please if sameone has any idea and can help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Since result is based on a topology you would have to change that in some way ... you can try add Remesh modifier before Decimator.

Comment: as vklidu assumed - your faces in the middle seem to be much bigger than on the poles so remeshing it is one possible way to solve that.